# Relative article 0px height with absolute inner elements

Tags: css, html

I have a container element which is positioned relatively so all absolute children within this parent are overlaid.
The following element is overlapped by the container caused by a rendered 0px height.
Is there a solution without using JS to give the container the height of an inner element?

The HTML:

```
<article class="modul header_modul drei_boxen_slider ">
       <section class="element">
        <div class="modul_image_wrapper">
         <img src="img/pic.jpg" alt="title"/>
         <div class="modul_image_title"><h4>Image Title</h4></div>
       </div>
     </section>
      <section class="element">
        <div class="modul_image_wrapper">
         <img src="img/pic.jpg" alt="title"/>
         <div class="modul_image_title"><h4>Image Title</h4></div>
       </div>
     </section>
      <section class="element">
        <div class="modul_image_wrapper">
         <img src="img/pic.jpg" alt="title"/>
         <div class="modul_image_title"><h4>Image Title</h4></div>
       </div>
     </section>
   </article>
```

The CSS:

```
.drei_boxen_slider{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;


}
.drei_boxen_slider .element{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: Not when you are using `position: absolute;` on the child

Answer (score 0):

```
// test you this code
.drei_boxen_slider {
 bottom: 0;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 .drei_boxen_slider .element {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```